# Why are the symbols in my list of open windows repaced by a missing file?

Tags: icons, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

I have the problem, that after an upgrade 14.04 -> 16.04 -> 18.04 and the corresponding change of Unity -> GNOME many of my programs do not show up correctly in the list of open windows (typically on the left side).

I put an image of the problem here:

[image: Part of screenshot with the missing program icon]

Above the icon of GIMP there is another icon that seems to be shown for a whole set of programs. Of course this is not nice as I have to hover the icon with the mouse to see what program it represents using the tool tips or the right-click menu. In this example the program is a KDE program (I like kile much more for TeX-writing than any other program I am aware of). In recent versions of ubuntu this did not cause any problem.
Other programs do have the very same effect.

What can I do to correct this problem?

Comment: Have you tried installing a couple of other icon themes?

Comment: Which themes are you referring to? `$ dpkg -l | grep '^i' | grep icon-theme | awk '{print $2}'` results in some entries: `adwaita-icon-theme`, `breeze-icon-theme`, `gnome-icon-theme`, `gnome-icon-theme-symbolic`, `hicolor-icon-theme`, `humanity-icon-theme`, and `oxygen-icon-theme`. So I think I have some icons at my hands. Under `/usr/share/icons` I find images with kile in the file name in various folders.

Comment: In that case, you can install GNOME Tweak Tools (from memory) and change from your current icon theme to something else in the hope that the icons will reappear. Also see if https://askubuntu.com/questions/722708/how-do-i-refresh-the-icon-cache helps.

Comment: I tried out all available icon sets in the tweak tool. None did help. Also rebuilding the cache did not help unless I need to relogin/restart.

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of ideas but hope you manager to sort things out!