# How to import a vector graphic to the icon database

Tags: icons, vector

I have extracted a *.ico file from a exe file. Its a vector graphic file, gimp says its size is 32x32. I copied the file to /home/user/.local/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/apps/ and updated the icon database. But i can't add the icon to a desktop file and can't find the icon in the Yad Icon Browser. Is there an other way to import such icon to the database?

It works when i use the absolute path in the desktop file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I refresh the icon cache?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/722708/how-do-i-refresh-the-icon-cache)

Comment: i know how to refresh the database? but whats the correct subfolder for the image? i've copied it to the 32x32 subfolder and refreshed the database without sucess. Is *ico a supported format?