# How can I fix missing icons for RStudio project and RData files in Ubuntu 20.10+?

Tags: icons, 20.10, 21.04

Starting with Ubuntu 20.10, and continuing in Ubuntu 21.04, the icon for RStudio project files and RData files was no longer showing up. It had been my experience in prior Ubuntu versions that these icons were correctly associated with the proper mimetype after installing RStudio.

[image]

So first I made sure that RStudio still added a mimetype entry for these on installation, finding in `usr/share/mime/packages/rstudio.xml`

```xml
  <mime-type type="application/x-r-data">
    <comment>R Data File</comment>
    <glob pattern="*.RData"/>
    <glob pattern="*.Rdata"/>
    <glob pattern="*.rdata"/>
    <glob pattern="*.rda"/>
  </mime-type>

  <mime-type type="application/x-r-project">
    <comment>R Project</comment>
    <glob pattern="*.Rproj"/>
    <glob pattern="*.RProj"/>
    <glob pattern="*.rproj"/>
  </mime-type>
```

If, that wasn't the issue, I was a little stumped, so I checked to see if others had this problem. I sure enough found [an issue filed at Yaru's GitHub repository](https://github.com/ubuntu/yaru/issues/2334), but so far it seems like there hasn't been any movement on fixing this issue.<sup>1</sup> How can I get these icons back while we wait on the Yaru devs?

---

<sub>1. There *has* been *some* movement on the issue as filed, which affects **several** icon sets, but none of it on the *RStudio* icons.</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I noticed from [a discussion on a Fedora forum](https://www.spinics.net/linux/fedora/fedora-users/msg505290.html) that the `hicolor` icon set had the relevant `.png` files. So, first we need to copy those `.png` files into the Yaru set, which you can do with these commands:

```bsh
sudo cp /usr/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/mimetypes/application-x-r-data.png /usr/share/icons/Yaru/16x16/mimetypes/
sudo cp /usr/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/mimetypes/application-x-r-project.png /usr/share/icons/Yaru/16x16/mimetypes/
sudo cp /usr/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/mimetypes/application-x-r-data.png /usr/share/icons/Yaru/32x32/mimetypes/
sudo cp /usr/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/mimetypes/application-x-r-project.png /usr/share/icons/Yaru/32x32/mimetypes/
sudo cp /usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/mimetypes/application-x-r-data.png /usr/share/icons/Yaru/48x48/mimetypes/
sudo cp /usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/mimetypes/application-x-r-project.png /usr/share/icons/Yaru/48x48/mimetypes/
```

Next we need to refresh the icon cache, which for some reason for me didn't work without `touch`ing the root directory (h/t to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/884758)):

```bsh
sudo touch /usr/share/icons/Yaru
sudo gtk-update-icon-cache
```

Then either re-open or refresh the file explorer, and voila!

[image]

Now you can have your precious RStudio Project and RData icons in the meantime until they're properly back in Yaru.

Comment: Also works on Ubuntu 22.04. Thanks!