# Libreoffice very slow to open (Linux, Kubuntu)

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu, libreoffice

Recently Libreoffice has become very slow to open on my computer. It takes several minutes just to open. My cOS is Kubuntu20.04.

I have tried to:

- purge it and reinstall it
- install the latest version from a deb package

I have also tried to follow the tips on [this page](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/libreoffice-runs-slow/53679/2) though my OS is Linux:

- run LibreOffice in safe mode
- toggle openCL
- remove anti-aliasing

It changed nothing.

I have run a `strace libreoffice` but I can not interprete the results. Here are the last few lines that I get before libreoffice gets struck. I can add the whole report if needed.

```
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/tmp/OSL_PIPE_1000_SingleOfficeIPC_b910dfc6e06b87d13cbea62e8047c298"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
close(3)                                = 0
stat("/proc/version", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=20480, ...}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/dev/block/8:0/queue/rotational", O_RDONLY) = 3
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 8392704, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_STACK, -1, 0) = 0x7f7d73a20000
mprotect(0x7f7d73a21000, 8388608, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE) = 0
clone(child_stack=0x7f7d7421f630, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, parent_tid=[25343], tls=0x7f7d74220700, child_tidptr=0x7f7d742209d0) = 25343
futex(0x55daba28d610, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
futex(0x55daba28d610, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
futex(0x55daba28d838, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL) = 0
futex(0x55daba28d840, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
read(5, "/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd"..., 4096) = 209
close(5)                                = 0
pipe([3, 4])                            = 0
clone(child_stack=0x7f7d7421f630, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, parent_tid=[25364], tls=0x7f7d74220700, child_tidptr=0x7f7d742209d0) = 25364
futex(0x55daba28e890, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
futex(0x55daba28e890, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
futex(0x55daba28d838, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL) = 0
futex(0x55daba28d840, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
close(4)                                = 0
futex(0x55daba28ece8, FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET_PRIVATE|FUTEX_CLOCK_REALTIME, 0, {tv_sec=1639832977, tv_nsec=373455000}, FUTEX_BITSET_MATCH_ANY
```

The command `apt-cache policy libreoffice` gives

```
libreoffice:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:7.2.3~rc2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1~lo1
  Version table:
     1:7.2.3~rc2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1~lo1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     1:7.1.7-0ubuntu0.21.04.1~bpo20.04.1 100
        100 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 Packages
     1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 500
        500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 Packages
     1:6.4.2-0ubuntu3 500
        500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
```

The command `lowriter --version` gives:

```
LibreOffice 7.2.3.2 20(Build:2)
```

Do you know what the problem is and what I could do ?

Thank you

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy libreoffice` and `lowriter --version` to the question.

Answer (score 2):

One thing that could cause it is an abnormally large number of installed fonts (could something have done that recently?) or a corrupted font cache

Try running `sudo fc-cache -f -v` to reset your font cache.

If that doesn't work compare your `~/.local/share/fonts`, `/usr/share/fonts/` and `/usr/local/share/fonts` contents with that of a fresh installation (e.g. install Ubuntu on a VM) i.e.

```bsh
cd /usr/share/fonts
find . >> ~/fontlist.txt
cd /usr/local/share/fonts
find . >> ~/fontlist.txt
cd ~/.local/share/fonts
find . >> ~/fontlist.txt

diff ~/fontlist.txt ~/vmlist.txt
```

to see if it's abnormally larger (or maybe there's a rogue font, try backing up your fonts and replace them with the contents of a stock installation, reset the cache, and try again)

**Edit:** Just to try things out, try refreshing your [icon cache](https://askubuntu.com/questions/722708/how-do-i-refresh-the-icon-cache) as well.

Comment: Thanks! Running `sudo fc-cache -f -v` and `sudo update-icon-caches /usr/share/icons/*` helped me. It improved performance a lot. I have Ubuntu 20.04 and Libreoffice 6.4.7.2 installed via snap-store

Answer (score 0):

You have to try resetting its per-user configuration by

```
mv ~/.config/libreoffice ~/.config/libreoffice_old
```

and then start LibreOffice again.

Comment: Please note that this will also delete any basic/python macros that might have been created by the user and all customization done for libreoffice. So better to take back up of the folder before removing it.

Comment: I did it because I had no important macro but the problem is still there :(

Comment: @Anoikis : I use Libreoffice appimage and have not experienced any such issue. while the issue will get sorted out you may also try downloading appimage from libreoffice site and see if it helps.